# Speeding up reshaping person to period-format dataframe in R

Tags: performance, r, reshape, data-manipulation

I have a dataset with longitudinal data in a person-oriented format, as such:

```
pid varA_1 varB_1 varA_2 varB_2 varA_3 varB_3 ...
1   1      1      0      3      2      1
2   0      1      0      2      2      1
...
50k 1      0      1      3      1      0
```

This results in a large dataframe, with minimum 50k observations and 90 variables measured for up to 29 periods.

I would like to get a more period-oriented format, as such:

```
pid index start stop varA varB varC ...
1   1     ...
1   2     
...
1   29
2   1
```

I have tried different approaches for reshaping the dataframe (`*apply`, `plyr`, `reshape2`, loops, appending vs. prefilling all numeric matrices, etc.,), but do not seem to get a decent processing time (+40min for subsets). I have picked up various hints along the way on what to avoid, but I'm still not sure if I miss some bottleneck or possible speedup.

Is there an optimal way to approach this kind of data-processing, so that I can evaluate the best-case processing time I can achieve in pure R-code? There have been [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860913/r-performance-with-data-reshaping) on Stackoverflow, but they did not result in convincing answers...

Comment: Its not totally clear how your example maps to what you want. Where's the start and stop values in the example input? How ragged is your data? Do some people have only VarA and B and some have VarC and D? Does the number always go up to the same for each person? Is it padded with NAs otherwise? A complete tiny example would be ideal!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's build the data example (I am using 5e3 instead of 50e3 to avoid memory problems with my configuration):

```
nObs <- 5e3
nVar <- 90
nPeriods <- 29

dat <- matrix(rnorm(nObs*nVar*nPeriods), nrow=nObs, ncol=nVar*nPeriods)

df <- data.frame(id=seq_len(nObs), dat)

nmsV <- paste('Var', seq_len(nVar), sep='')
nmsPeriods <- paste('T', seq_len(nPeriods), sep='')

nms <- c(outer(nmsV, nmsPeriods, paste, sep='_'))
names(df)[-1] <- nms
```

And now with `stats::reshape` you change the format:

```
df2 <- reshape(df, dir = "long", varying = 2:((nVar*nPeriods)+1), sep = "_")
```

I am not sure if this is the *fast* solution you are looking for.

Comment: Your example helped me figure out why reshape was not working. Now that it does, this build-in function does what I need & a lot faster then my custom code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The well-aged stack() function can be very fast, if things fit into memory.

For large set, using (transparent) sqlite database as an intermediate is best. Try Gabor's package sqldf, there are many examples on googlecode.

http://code.google.com/p/sqldf/